# Is ‘malarkey’ an acceptable word to use today?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Is it acceptable today to use ‘malarkey’ to describe an idea that is nonsensical?

Or are there better terms to use?

Comment: Although I know 'nonsense' is the standard definition, I've always had the impression that it's used more as a synonym of *fuss* or *brouhaha* in England, where I've heard it a lot over the years. Can any English people back me up on this?

Comment: @legatrix Cambridge defines it as '_silly behaviour_ or nonsense'. I agree with you that I think of it as referring to pointless activity rather than spoken nonsense.

Comment: @Void - have you done any research? The word 'malarkey' is extremely common in British English. Are Brits, Australians, Kiwis, Irish etc people equivalent to 'no one'?

Comment: @legatrix - it's more used for pointless or time wasting activity, e.g. I wanted to own an elephant but I found out I had to complete a lot of forms and buy a wildlife licence, and I couldn't be bothered with all that malarkey. Not really fuss or brouhaha.

Comment: Research - "I love the flavours of a Bakewell tart, but I really can't be bothered to faff around with making pastry and baking it blind and all that malarkey" - June 2020

Comment: @MichaelHarvey your comments would make a better answer than we currently have at least for British English.

Comment: @mdewey - considering the ease of researching this, the question is borderline close-votable for lack of research, or if the query is whether it is acceptable 'today', likewise for being opinion-based. I have, however, provided an answer.

Comment: @Void - expressions come and go. Malarky, as a number of answers noted, is a frequently used word by the now President-Elect in the United States. So, in the US, the word is likely to become more recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Ngram Viewer statistics](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=malarkey%2Cpiffle%2Cclaptrap%2Cbalderdash%2Chogwash&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmalarkey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpiffle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclaptrap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbalderdash%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chogwash%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmalarkey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpiffle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclaptrap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbalderdash%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chogwash%3B%2Cc0), the word *malarkey* becomes more popular through years, however, I would recommend that you use other more common [synonyms](https://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/malarkey) like *hogwash* or *claptrap* (if you do not want to use *nonsense* as the most obvious description):

[image]

Comment: I am afraid it is not a synonym of either of them at least in its common use in the UK so the relative frequencies are slightly misleading.

Comment: @mdewey In question was stated, that the word should mean `an idea that is nonsensical`. For this meaning all words on the chart are suitable.

Comment: If the OP wants a synonym for _malarkey_ then _rigmarole_ or _taradiddle_ would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Joe Biden seems to use it [pretty regularly](https://www.nj.com/politics/2020/10/at-final-presidential-debate-bidens-malarkey-abraham-lincoln-and-poor-boys-win-big.html). It's not a common word, but one that is widely understood. It has a feel of being playfully old-fashioned.

Answer (score 3):

The word 'malarkey' (less common, and mainly US, 'malarky') is common in British English, as used in the UK, Australia, New Zealand, Ireland, etc, and is used by Americans including Joe Biden recently. It is often used to discuss something considered nonsensical, pointless or a waste of time

> I wanted to own an elephant but I found out I had to complete a lot of
> forms and buy a wildlife licence, and I couldn't be bothered with all
> that malarkey.
>
> I love the flavours of a Bakewell tart, but I really can't be bothered
> to faff around with making pastry and baking it blind and all that
> malarkey.
>
> He thinks that everything politicians say is a bunch of malarkey.
>
> I like the socializing but I can't be bothered with dressing up and all that malarkey.

[Malarkey (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/malarkey)

[Malarkey (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malarkey)